# displayHTML in Azure Databricks shows only a small slice of a leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, azure-databricks, mapview

I'm attempting to display an HTML file (a leaflet map) using `displayHTML()` inside a notebook. The file is created with the R mapview package, after following https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/visualizations/htmlwidgets.html to make it all work.  The HTML file is valid and I can open it in a browser window with full functionality.

What's happening in the notebook is that in the cell output, the map is only rendering as a very short slice of the map:

[image]

The visual appears to be fully functional, but I cannot figure out how to increase the size of the render/display area. I imagine it's either something within the HTML itself (like it's fitting to the size of the pane of the Databricks cell output, which it's thinking is a single line, perhaps), or there's a Databricks setting I'm not seeing.  Resizing the cell output with a click-drag on the bottom-right corner has no effect.

Is there a way to make the map take up more space in a cell output?

DBR 9.1 LTS

Comment: Would also like to know how to do this (and haven't got as far as you unfortunately Andrew)